# Buttons don't work when adding a window mousedown event

Tags: c#, wpf

I current have custom close and minimise buttons for my application, they work fine. However when I add the `MouseDown` event to the window (to make the window draggable), all buttons on the page stop working. Is there a solution to this?

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```cs
namespace Test_Window
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Minimise_Window(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void Close_Window(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
        private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
                DragMove();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```cs
<Window x:Class="Test_Window.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Daily_Encouragement"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Topmost="True"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="776,4,4,426" MouseUp="Close_Window">
            <TextBlock Text="X"  Background="Transparent" Margin="2,2,6,0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="747,4,29,423" MouseUp="Minimise_Window">
            <Frame Background="Black" Margin="5,12,5,8" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You might want to edit your question Title. :D  Those `assing` events are a pain in the butt!

Comment: @devlincarnate Whoops, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the MouseDown event on the Window, because it will mess with the tunneling/bubbling "MouseDown" event handling for everything inside your window, such as your buttons.  Instead, use the MouseMove event on the Window and your issue should be resolved.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Test_Window.MainWindow"
        ...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" MouseMove="Window_MouseMove">
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        DragMove();
}
```